# connection timed out error in online mode and could not open file in offline mode - android studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, android-library, android-gradle-3.0

```
repositories {
    maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.PhilJay:MPAndroidChart:v2.2.2'
}
```

I am getting the `Error:Connection timed out: connect` in online mode whereas while changing the gradle setting to offline, I could not open the library.

Comment: Proxy problem? Could you open https://jitpack.io in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps, your internet connection is too slow.
You can download this library from `github` and import in your project.

Here is `github` repository link:
https://github.com/PhilJay/MPAndroidChart

Just click on download **button** then select **download ZIP** and after downloading, copy the folder **MPChartLib** and paste into your project root directory and `compile` with `gradle`.

In your **settings.gradle**, `include ':app', ':MDChartLib'`
and `build.gradle(Module:app)`,   `compile project(':MDChartLib')`

Answer (score 0):

Please connect to "Internet" and make it sync again.

Comment: It is connected always